# How to show hidden element along with animation on scrolling windows scroll bar?

Tags: html, jquery, css, animation

I have a div element that I have hide by applying .intro class. Now I want to show this hidden div along with animation on scroll bar Scrolling. I have defined my own animation within fadeInUp class. Now if I try to remove  .intro class, the div will animate after being showing. But I don't want this. I just want div should show along with animation. The animation should not show after being showing a div.
Here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 100) {
    $('#demo').removeClass('intro');
    $('#demo').addClass('fadeInUp');
  } 
});
```

My CSS is something like this

```
.intro{
    display: none;
}
    
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,100%,0)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
        transform: translate3d(0,100%,0)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        -ms-transform: none;
        transform: none
    }
}

.fadeInUp {
    visibility: visible;
    animation-duration: 9s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIUp;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

HTML is something like this

```
<div id="demo" class=" intro" style="height:100px;width: 100px; background-color:red"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit***: We had to do three things to solve this issue-

1. Put **animation-fill-mode: both;** in the fadeInUp class.
2. Change the name of the animation as there was a naming conflict: animation-name and the class name were the same.
3. Some tiny changes in the JS part to select appropriate classes (check below code).

[Working demo](https://codepen.io/ni_l/full/QWKgMjK) & [Code](https://codepen.io/ni_l/pen/QWKgMjK)!

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo" class="intro redbox"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
      height: 1600px;
}
.intro{
    opacity:0;
}
.redbox {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUpA {
    0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}
    100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}
}

@keyframes fadeInUpA {
    0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

100% {
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: none;
   -ms-transform: none;
   transform: none;
}
}

.fadeInUp {
    visibility: visible;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUpA;
    animation-name: fadeInUpA;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

**JS**

```
myID = document.getElementById("demo");
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).scroll(function() {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y < 200) {
    myID.className = "redbox intro"
}
else{
   myID.className = "redbox fadeInUp"
}
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't want to use fadeIn() or fadeout() methods and also have already seen this solution you mentioned above. I just want to use my own animation that I have mentioned within fadeInUp CSS class.

Comment: I've updated my answer! Hope this one addresses the issue that you've raised! Now you can use your own custom animation! @hassan

Comment: Thanks, man it is is working you saved me. @NiL